# Running R script through qsub

Tags: r, bash, pbs, qsub, rscript

I am trying to run an `R` script called `test.r` through `qsub`. My `R` script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
x <- 1
write.csv(x,"test.csv")
```

If in Ubuntu terminal I type `R CMD BATCH test.r`, then the script behaves as planned; `test.csv` gets exported in the same directory.

However if I create a `bash` script called `testbash.sh` and run it through the command `qsub testbash.sh`; it will run without errors but the output won't be there.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
R CMD BATCH test.r
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your R script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
x <- 1
print(getwd())
write.csv(x,"test.csv")
```

When you run a script via `qsub`, the script is normally running in another server, and by default as in your home directory. You need to change to the original directory in your script, there is a variable `PBS_O_WORKDIR` for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#PBS -N qsub_R_test
echo We are in the $PWD directory
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
echo We are now in $PBS_O_WORKDIR, running an R script.
R --vanilla < test.r > test.log 2> test.log
```

I normally cannot use `R CMD BATCH`, but redirection to `R -vanilla` works. You can also specify options for the PBS in the script, starting with `#PBS`, like the job name in this case (`qsub_R_test`).

You can get a more detailed list of qsub parameters here: 
http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/louhi_guide/batch_jobs/commands/qsub

And an example of a PBS script here:
http://bose.utmb.edu/Compu_Center/Cluster_users/PBS%20HOWTO/PBS_HOW_TO.html

Answer (score 1):

You may be doing it wrong. If you have a shebang line like

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
```

then "simply" do `chmod 0755 test.r` on the file, and run it:

```
./test.r
```

That should work, and you can then have that invocation in your qsub-called script.